# Ruby FrozenString error in Sidekiq Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails and trying to use a Sidekiq worker, but at some point I'm running into an issue where the worker calls a view, the view calls a concern, and then the concern isn't able to update a variable in its function because of the FrozenString error.

For example, here's how my worker looks:

```
class ReportGeneratorWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker, ReportHelper
    sidekiq_options queue: Rails.env.to_sym
    
    def perform
        ac_base = ApplicationController.new
        body_html = ac_base.render_to_string template: "common/report_templates/generate_pdf.html.erb", layout: false
    end
end
```

Again, the view inserts text that leverages a concern, but the concern doesn't allow it to update. See below for example:

```
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007fec8ceea400>>)> html
=> "<ul>"
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007fec8ceea400>>)> html.class.name                                          
=> "String"
[5] pry(#<#<Class:0x00007fec8ceea400>>)> html << "Hello"                                                                                                                 
FrozenError: can't modify frozen String
from (pry):5:in `replacement_text'
```

Any idea why this is happening? If I define the variable again from the Pry console, then it actually works:

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x0000557f07a25130>>)> html
=> "<ul>"
[2] pry(#<#<Class:0x0000557f07a25130>>)> html << "TEST"
FrozenError: can't modify frozen String
from (pry):2:in `replacement_text'
[3] pry(#<#<Class:0x0000557f07a25130>>)> html = "<ul>"
=> "<ul>"
[4] pry(#<#<Class:0x0000557f07a25130>>)> html << "TEST"
=> "<ul>TEST"
[5] pry(#<#<Class:0x0000557f07a25130>>)>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue by replacing `<<` with `+=`.